# Default datatype mapping in elasticsearch

Tags: mapping, elasticsearch

The following are the contents of `config/default_mapping.json`:

```
{
    "_default_" : [
    {
        "int_template" : {
                "match": "*",
                "match_mapping_type": "int",
                "mapping": {
                        "type": "string"
                }
        }
    ]
}
```

Want i want ES to do is to pick out all numbers from my logs and map them as strings.

**Use case-**

After clearing all indexes- `curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/_all'`, i run this to send the following to ES (through fluentd's tailf plugin)-

`echo "{\"this\" : 134}" >> /home/user/logs/program-data/logs/tiger/tiger.log`

Elastic happily creates the initial indexes. Now, to test weather my default_mapping works, i send a `string` at the value where i previously sent an `int`.

`echo "{\"this\" : \"ABC\"}" >> /home/user/logs/program-data/logs/tiger/tiger.log`

**Exception caught by ES-**

```
org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperParsingException: failed to parse [this]
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.core.AbstractFieldMapper.parse(AbstractFieldMapper.java:398)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.serializeValue(ObjectMapper.java:618)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.object.ObjectMapper.parse(ObjectMapper.java:471)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:513)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.DocumentMapper.parse(DocumentMapper.java:457)
    at org.elasticsearch.index.shard.service.InternalIndexShard.prepareCreate(InternalIndexShard.java:342)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardIndexOperation(TransportShardBulkAction.java:401)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.bulk.TransportShardBulkAction.shardOperationOnPrimary(TransportShardBulkAction.java:155)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction.performOnPrimary(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:556)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.replication.TransportShardReplicationOperationAction$AsyncShardOperationAction$1.run(TransportShardReplicationOperationAction.java:426)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ABC"
    at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:438)
    at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:478)
    at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.support.AbstractXContentParser.longValue(AbstractXContentParser.java:89)
```

What could be wrong here?

**Update-**

My `default_mapping.json` now looks like-

```
{
        "_default_": {
            "dynamic_templates": [
                {
                    "string_template": {
                        "match": "*",
                        "mapping": {
                            "type": "string"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'd suggest not to use file system based configuration or mappings. Just do it via api.

Your mapping is malformed, as you have the type name (`_default_`) but you don't specify that what you are submitting is a dynamic template.

As for the content, I'd remove that `match_mapping_type` if you want to map everything as a string.

Comment: Could you perhaps do a pastebin of the proper json configuration? i have been struggling with this for hours now.

Comment: Have a look [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-root-object-type.html#_dynamic_templates) for the right json, there's an example...

Comment: If i want this number to string change across the board, what should i put in the place of `"person"` in the  given json example? `*`?

Comment: `person` is the typename in the example, `_default_` is good in your case, it will apply to all types. What you forgot is the `dynamic_templates` part under it.

Comment: Confirming that the file would be called `default_mapping.json` and would be placed in `config/default_mapping.json`

Comment: i've updated the answer with the mapping as you suggested. Do i need to nest the entire thing under `"mappings" : { }` too?

Comment: *"I'd suggest not to use file system based configuration or mappings. Just do it via api."* The [put mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-put-mapping.html#indices-put-mapping) method, it seems is applicable only for specific indexes. How do i specify that i am passing the default mapping? `_all`?

Comment: Default mapping means that it applies to all types under the current index. You can use index templates if you want to apply it to multiple indices (that have yet to be created).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46855/discussion-between-erbdex-and-javanna)